# ag-grid onGridReady not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, grid, ag-grid

I want to load ag-grid inside a button click. I have tried two approaches but none is working

My code : First Method

```
 onBtnClick(){
    this.gridOptions ={
        onGridReady : function(){
            console.log("print");
        }
    }
}
```

Second method:

```
onBtnClick(){
    this.onGridReady();
}
onGridReady(){
   this.gridApi = params.api;
    console.log("print");
}
```

First method not working. Second method says api is not defined

Comment: Can you share the HTML also? Just want to make sure that gridOptions is bound correctly

Comment: Am using [gridOptions] = "gridOptions" (gridReady) ="onGridReady ($event)

Answer (score 3):

You can have this approach.

1. Have a flag in your component when to display the grid.
2. Use this flag to conditionally display the grid using `*ngIf`
3. Set this flag value on button click

This way, the template having `ag-grid` won't be rendered until the flag is set. When it's set, the template will be rendered and `onGridReady` will be called.

```
<button (click)="btnClick()">Display grid</button>
<ag-grid-angular *ngIf="displayGrid"
  #agGrid
  ......
></ag-grid-angular>


btnClick(){
  this.displayGrid = true;
}
```

Check this working example: [ag-grid display on button click](https://plnkr.co/edit/iisbOBTfyD9S0wTlHqfn?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if `ag-grid`is connected to `onGridReady`?

It should look something like that:

```
<ag-grid-angular
 ...
 (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should share more of you code, it's unclear what you are doing.

You must make sure your gridOptions are fully set up BEFORE the grid initializes. (Doing this on a button is too late)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.gridOptions.onGridReady = gridReadyHandler;
}
gridReadyHandler = (params: GridReadyEvent) => {
  this.gridApi = params.api;
  console.log("grid is done loading", this.gridApi);
}
```